# Keep getting error index out of range when using python generated csv file

Tags: python, csv, bioinformatics

I am having some issues with my coding. This code works, but only when you originally saved the file as csv.

However when I have python make the csv file and insert it into this code it says over and over again index out of range my csv file consists of three columns with about 57,000 rows each.

Ignore the raw_data part this basically comes from a much larger code but my problem is in here:

```
import csv
data = [] #Buffer list 
p = raw_input("Whatever you want in here man")
with open(r'/home/gmabry/Desktop/out.csv', "rb") as the_file:
    reader = csv.reader(the_file, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:

        try:
            new_row = [row[0], row[1], row[2]]
            #Basically ´write the rows to a list
            data.append(new_row)
        except IndexError as e:
            print e
            pass

    with open("/home/gmabry/Desktop/readyfordb.csv", "w+") as to_file:
        writer = csv.writer(to_file, delimiter=",")
        for new_row in data:
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: Just examine your `row` to figure out it's contents, it's length etc. by printing it for example.

Comment: that helped. my delimiter was a semicolon and the code asks for comma.i forgot i was trying to change it. thanks